# Neural Network Learning in Octave/Python to Computer the Cost for Specific DataSet

Tags: python, octave

I am learning Neural Networks via Octave and Python and using exercises from https://github.com/leejaymin/machine_learning_coursera_python_octave

In the Neural Networks exercise, I get the following command to load the data in octave

```
load('ex4data1.mat');
m = size(X, 1);
% Randomly select 100 data points to display
sel = randperm(size(X, 1));
sel = sel(1:100);
displayData(X(sel, :));
% Load the weights into variables Theta1 and Theta2
load('ex4weights.mat');
% Unroll parameters 
nn_params = [Theta1(:) ; Theta2(:)];
```

A similar code in python is

```
data = loadmat('ex4data1.mat')
data.keys()
y = data['y']
X = np.c_[np.ones((data['X'].shape[0],1)), data['X']]
print('X:',X.shape, '(with intercept)')
print('y:',y.shape)
weights = loadmat('ex3weights.mat')
weights.keys()
theta1, theta2 = weights['Theta1'], weights['Theta2']
print('theta1 :', theta1.shape)
print('theta2 :', theta2.shape)
params = np.r_[theta1.ravel(), theta2.ravel()]
print('params :', params.shape)
```

The dataset which I currently have is only this. Three nodes are inputs and three nodes are hidden and one will be output.

[image]

I get confused now about how to process the above pic data to the .mat file or what I am missing here. How can I transform my pic data to .mat so that I will be further processed to compute the cost for a few iterations only?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking how you can convert that image to a data file, so that you can use it with your octave code?

Comment: yes into the .mat file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not asking for a way to automatically convert the image into data, and you actually have the data in a file somewhere, then all you have to do is write it as a matrix:

```matlab
X = [ 1000, 3, 1000000, 1;
      1200, 2, 1200000, 0;
       900, 2,  900000, 1;
      1500, 3, 1500000, 0;
       800, 1,  800000, 1;   % presumably the picture has a typo here?
    ]
```

and then save the matrix to a .mat file

```matlab
save data.mat X
```